# Specialized templates for pointer and c-style array variables

Tags: c++, template-specialization, c++98

I have the following code which works, when I compile the code with C++11 enabled. Is it also possible to write the specializations such that it will work with a C++98 compiler?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <type_traits>
#include <cstdint>

template<typename T, typename std::enable_if_t<!std::is_pointer<T>::value, int> = 0>
void CheckSize(T const)
{
    cout << "sizeof(data): " << sizeof(T) << endl;
}

template<typename T, typename std::enable_if_t<std::is_pointer<T>::value, int> = 0>
void CheckSize(T const)
{
    cout << "sizeof(data) (pointer): " << sizeof(std::remove_pointer<T>) << endl;
}

template<typename T, size_t N>
void CheckSize(T const (&)[N])
{
    cout << "sizeof(data) (array): " << sizeof(T) * N << endl;
}

int main()
{
    uint8_t bufferNumber{0};
    CheckSize(bufferNumber);
    uint8_t bufferArray[] = {1,2,3,4,5,6};
    CheckSize(bufferArray);
    uint8_t *bufferPointer{nullptr};
    CheckSize(bufferPointer);

    return 0;
}
```

I also don't understand why the compiler can't apply the specialization when writing:

```
template<typename T>
void CheckSize(T const)
{
    cout << "sizeof(data): " << sizeof(T) << endl;
}

template<typename T>
void CheckSize(T const*)
{
    cout << "sizeof(data) (pointer): " << sizeof(T) << endl;
}
```

MSVC2015 will print an error message that the function call is ambigious for the overloaded function for the `bufferArray` variable and MinGW will use the `CheckSize(T const)` function for the `bufferPointer` variable.

Comment: Boost provides `enable_if` and a lot/all of the traits that you can use in C++98.  If you have to use C++98 then you should consider using boost instead of trying to implement it all yourself.

Comment: what is the point creating this template if it prints `sizeof(T) * N`? Same value is provided by `sizeof(bufferArray)`. What you wanted to achieve?

Comment: It's just example code here. I need the size of the data because I want to use the underlying data in the function (copy it into a buffer).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As it was mentioned in the comments, one option is to use the [boost::enable_if](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_66_0/libs/core/doc/html/core/enable_if.html)

Another option is to use partial template specialization for classes instead of function overloading:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <type_traits>
#include <cstdint>

using namespace std;

template<typename T>
struct SizeChecker
{
    static void CheckSize(T const)
    {
        cout << "sizeof(data): " << sizeof(T) << endl;
    }
};

template<typename T>
struct SizeChecker<T*>
{
    static void CheckSize(T* const)
    {
        cout << "sizeof(data) (pointer): " << sizeof(T*) << endl;
    }
};

template<typename T, size_t N>
struct SizeChecker<T[N]>
{
    static void CheckSize(const T(&)[N])
    {
        cout << "sizeof(data) (array): " << sizeof(T) * N << endl;
    }
};

template <typename T>
void CheckSize(const T& val)
{
    SizeChecker<T>::CheckSize(val);
}

int main()
{
    char bufferNumber{0};
    CheckSize(bufferNumber);
    char bufferArray[] = {1,2,3,4,5,6};
    CheckSize(bufferArray);
    char *bufferPointer{NULL};
    CheckSize(bufferPointer);

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned in the comments, `enable_if` and the type traits you're using are implementable using C++98.  Boost provides implementations, and I would recommend using them if you're already using boost, but they're fairly simple to implement if you're not using boost:

```
template <bool b, typename T>
struct enable_if;

template <typename T>
struct enable_if<true, T>
{
    typedef T type;
};

template <typename T>
struct is_pointer
{
    const static bool value = false;
};

template <typename T>
struct is_pointer<T*>
{
    const static bool value = true;
};

template <typename T>
struct remove_pointer
{
    typedef T type;
};

template <typename T>
struct remove_pointer<T*>
{
    typedef T type;
};

template<typename T>
typename enable_if<!is_pointer<T>::value, void>::type
CheckSize(T const)
{
    std::cout << "sizeof(data): " << sizeof(T) << std::endl;
}

template<typename T>
typename enable_if<is_pointer<T>::value, void>::type
CheckSize(T const)
{
    std::cout << "sizeof(data) (pointer): " << sizeof(typename remove_pointer<T>::type) << std::endl;
}

template<typename T, size_t N>
void CheckSize(T const (&)[N])
{
    std::cout << "sizeof(data) (array): " << sizeof(T) * N << std::endl;
}
```

[Live Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/c59a4595d030a2df)

Alternatively, you could use partial specialization rather than SFINAE to select your overload.  Since functions can't be partially specialized, you can partially specialize a helper class:

```
template<typename T>
struct CheckSizeHelper
{
    static void size() {
        std::cout << "sizeof(data): " << sizeof(T) << std::endl;
    }
};

template<typename T>
struct CheckSizeHelper<T*>
{
    static void size() {
        std::cout << "sizeof(data) (pointer): " << sizeof(T) << std::endl;
    }
};

template<typename T, size_t N>
struct CheckSizeHelper<T[N]>
{
    static void size() {
        std::cout << "sizeof(data) (array): " << sizeof(T) * N << std::endl;
    }
};

template<typename T>
void CheckSize(T const&) {
    CheckSizeHelper<T>::size();
}
```

[Live Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/b6aeaf73faea78a0)